# Symfony 2 Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation HeaderBag headers

Tags: php, symfony

So in Symfony2 I need to do the following:

```
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective();
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective();
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective();
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective();
```

The above methods are inside:

```
namespace Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation;

class HeaderBag
```

I have it working by updating my app_dev.php and app.php and adding the following:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);

$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-cache', true);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('max-age', 0);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-store', true);
```

Is this the proper way to modify the headers of should I do something else ?

Kinda new to Symfony and I want to do everything the correct way.

Comment: many ways to Rome, if you want that header for all requests/responses your solution maybe okay if it works

Comment: Yeah it works, just didn't know if I needed to extend anything or do it in some fancy hipster way.

Comment: Have you looked at the http caching chapter? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html.  I think you might find your hipster methods there.

Comment: could you approve the answer if it's good?

Comment: I have approved your answer :) thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will work, but it isn't a best practice. One of the great powers of Symfony2 is his Event Based [kernel](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html), the better way IMO is to write a Listener on kernel.response Event for header changes. Moreover, for example, in this way you can check your route.

One hipster implementation could be found for the [HttpCache Listener](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/EventListener/HttpCacheListener.php), give also a look to his service [definition](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/cache.xml).